# TWIG date function displaying incorrect datetime

Tags: datetime, twig, symfony

I am displaying a list of datetimes from my database and using twig to format. This was working until today.

If I dump this: `{{ dump(time.clockedIn) }}`

I get this:

```
DateTime {#612 ▼
     +"date": "2017-02-03 17:54:20.000000"
     +"timezone_type": 3
     +"timezone": "America/New_York"
}
```

When I dump this: `{{ dump(time.clockedIn|date("m/d/Y h:m:s a")) }}`

I get this: `"02/03/2017 05:02:20 pm"`

I cannot find out why this changed. Any ideas?

Comment: The correct format is `h:i:s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{{ dump(time.clockedIn|date("m/d/Y g:i:s a")) }
```

As per the [Twig date documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html), you should be using `g:i:s a`.
Note that this documentation references [PHP's date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), where you'll see the proper format characters that you can use.

Comment: Both the comment from @DarkBee and your answer works. Is this something that recently changed? The one I was using was working fine before today.

Comment: I updated my answer with the links to the old documentation. You need to look at the PHP date function. I know it seems confusing, but I've seen a lot of postings on SO regarding formatting dates.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alvin!

Comment: @iamthestreets It could never be `m` for minutes as it's already been used for the months, hence the `2` as output and your first format `m/d/Y` :)

Comment: Thanks. That's strange cause I have been using it that way for weeks and it worked without any problems. I changed it and all is working now.